# Python reduce in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, reduce, functools

I am a Java developer; however, occasionally due to cold starts in aws lambda for Java, I decide to use python for simple lambdas since it doesn't require compilation, eliminating cold starts.

The problem:
I have a list of dictionaries, I retrieve this from Dynamo, in short a valid example is the following

```
[
   {
    "data":"data",
    "Count": 60
   },
   {
    "data":"data",
    "Count": 60
   }
]
```

I am trying to *reduce* this by getting the sum of the Count fields by doing the following; however, I don't understand what I am missing.

```
reduce(lambda x, y: int(x['Count']) +
                  int(y['Count']), query_response)
```

This fails with `"errorMessage": "'int' object is not iterable"`

What is the correct approach to doing this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just posted an answer but then noticed that I can't reproduce the problem. That error makes it sound like `query_response` is actually an int, not a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give `x` an initial value of 0:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> query_reponse = [
...    {
...     "data": "data",
...     "Count": 60
...    },
...    {
...     "data": "data",
...     "Count": 60
...    }
... ]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + y["Count"], query_reponse, 0)
120
```

Ideally, you would want to use more descriptive variable names, e.g.:

```
>>> reduce(lambda total, d: total + d["Count"], query_reponse, 0)
120
```

For more info look at the docs for [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)

As the other answer suggests you probably want to use `sum()` for small tasks like this. However, I do still think learning how `reduce` works is important with its prevalence in things like `PySpark/Spark` or other languages.

Comment: Thats a super simple miss on my part... Thanks a lot !

Comment: No worries most people only use reduce on a list where your initial approach works, and they get confused about how it works under the hood.

Answer (score 3):

To get a sum, use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum), not `reduce`.

```
>>> query_response = [{'data': 'data', 'Count': 60}, {'data': 'data', 'Count': 60}]
>>> sum(x['Count'] for x in query_response)
120
```

This also uses a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-expression).